# Jquery alert on click if no items are selected

Tags: jquery, function, alert

Can anyone tell me how to add a alert to this jQuery code. I would like to when people click on the button and nothing is selected it will alert the person, that you have not selected any value. Is this possible for this piece of code?

```
 //add items
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#basket_popup_outer').on('click', function () {
            hideBasketPopup();
        });
    });

    function addItemToBasket() {
        var size = $('#str_dropdown').val(),
            qty = $('#antal_dropdown').val();
        if (!isNaN(size) && !isNaN(qty)) {
            $.post('din-indkoebskurv.php', {
                varenr: $('#varenr').val(),
                str: size,
                antal: qty,
                async: "Y"
            }, function (data) {
                $('.basket_pris').html(data);
                $('#basket_popup_outer').show();
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    function hideBasketPopup() {
        $('#basket_popup_outer').hide();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: please share the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking deeply at the code in the addItemToBasket function add an else statement:

```
if (!isNaN(size) && !isNaN(qty)) {
   //add to basket
} else {
   alert('You have no items selected');
}
```

Comment: Many thanks mate:) My eyes was melting, but it works now. The simple else stament works wonders. thanks!

Comment: No problem, I know the feeling. A mate of mine recently introduced me to Rubber duck debugging (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and it works a treat!

Comment: Good I'm not the only one:D